# Deploying ASP.NET Core JavaScript Services to Azure Failing Node

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

I've got Visual Studio 2017 R3 installed and ASP.NET Core 2.0 release bits.  When I create a new web application with react it works locally and when I deploy to azure no problem (as expected).  I want to add node to the mix and the article written for core 2.0

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/spa-services

says:

Note: If you're deploying to an Azure web site, you don't need to do anything here — Node.js is installed and available in the server environments

I follow the steps on the article here on how to add nodeservices and that works locally.  My steps are:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/02/14/building-single-page-applications-on-asp-net-core-with-javascriptservices/

add services.AddNodeServices();
  create About controller and view
  put down myNodeModule.js

When I deploy to Azure I get an error when I browse to

http://webapplication220170908032616.azurewebsites.net/home/about

I added the environment variable ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT and set it to Production. I verified that by adding an tag helper to another page.

The error I'm seeing is:

An error occurred while processing your request.
Request ID: 0HL7N1AN8GM1N:00000002

I've not used Azure for a while so a little rusty.

Comment: Did you tried to set to development enviroment (or add developer error page middleware) to see the error?

Comment: What would I add?  Developer middleware I would think would not help me for a production problem.

Comment: Just for help you see the error more detailed =/ (only an idea)

Comment: Hi @PeterKellner, did you ever get this working?  I have the same problem, and I believe it's because my app service sandbox only has dotnet core 2 runtime, and not nodejs by default.  From what I'm reading, if I want both, I have to run a VM instead.  But the MSDN blog post you link to implies it should have worked, once upon a time..?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience deployments to Azure for .NET Core have failed when I did not have a proper Runtime Identifier specified in the .csproj file.

I use the following in my projects and stopped seeing the errors.

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <RuntimeIdentifiers>win7-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and I found that it was because the version of Node installed by default was v4.8.2 (the current distro-stable version for Ubuntu 16.04).  I ran the following script to install Node 8.x:

```
cd ~
apt-get update && apt-get install -y gnupg
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x -o nodesource_setup.sh
# You might want to inspect nodesource_setup.sh before blindly running it
# vi nodesource_setup.sh
bash nodesource_setup.sh
apt-get install -y nodejs
```

(Credit to DigitalOcean: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Now my nodejs is v8.11.2, and my dotnet core app can run with NodeServices.